# iOS Color Transition Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, colors

My main Navigation Bar Color is a dark red. But when I fullsize view a picture, I want to have a black one. But it looks as the following:

[image: Color Transition]

Anybody knows why the transition isn't very smooth?

I set the color in the fullsize-image view controller in the viewWillAppear Method, and revert it to the red color in the viewWillDisappear Method.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: I see no "gradient" in this story. And I see no problem. My suggestion is: don't worry, be happy, move on.

Comment: Sorry, i meant transition, not gradient...

Comment: I still see no problem. How it looks is how it looks. Move on.

Comment: @matt If he wants to try making a gradient navbar transition there's nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

It is cross-fading your navigation bar because this is the only allowed animation for navigation bars. I don't think there's any other way to make it do a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use this:

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you give give navigation bar color as clear color i guess but you can overcome this by declaring it in Appdelegate file so that it can be applied in all ViewControllers like below,

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`   `{`
   `// Override point for customization after application launch.`
   `UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = UIColor.red`
   `UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.white`
   `UINavigationBar.appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]`

`return true`
`}`

i hope it helps you out.good luck.